# Get same html body in different requests

Tags: http, dart, networking, get

I'm calling HTTP requests on the same URL multiple times. But every time I get a different body. What's the reason behind that. And what should I do?

```
main() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print(await getBody('https://google.com'));
  }
}

Future<String> getBody(String lyricsUrl) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(lyricsUrl));
  return response.body.length.toString();
}
```

[Here is the output](https://ibb.co/xmQdP6p)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are printing is the length of complete text obtained from the request. So, this includes lot of things like : html code of website which include the body of the page, other text on the page, js functions , etc.. These all would be same for each request you make. But the request also returns a set of parameters like KEI, KEXPI strings which are part of the script for windows.google..

So, if you try printing the complete request text instead of the length alone, you would observe something like below whose values are different for different requests. Thus this is cause of different lengths for different requests.

```
window.google={kEI:\'dzPQYPiJ4fs6rTzssOTwAk\',
kEXPI:\'0,772215,1,52320,56873,954,5105,206,4804,2316,383,246,5,
23,5250,16232,10,1106274,1197730,522,31,328984,51224,16114,28684,
17572,4859,1361,9290,3027,3891,13691,4020,978,13228,3847,10622,
1141,7509,2,276,4516,2778,919,5081,885,710,1277,2212,530,149,1943,
6297,108,3406,606,2023,1777,520,12370,603,2624,1989,856,7,5599,
6755,5096,7539,338,4928,108,3407,908,2,231,2614,2397,1027,6441,
3277,3,576,1014,1,54423,149,5990,5333,991,1661,4,1528,2304,1236,
5803,74,1983,2626,2015,1300,2767,7434,3824,3050,2658,872,3291,80,56,
462,2595,31,13628,2305,639,7079,10535,665,2521,3261,2575,2047,2047,
17,3121,6,908,3,3541,1,14710,1814,283,38,351,2,1,3,517,5992,6754,
432,552,4788,2,1394,1498,35,1273,1715,2,3037,20,483,1534,3244,297,
10,147,1067,3,33,3,1343,1461,3271,626,158,254,494,1454,923,93,545,
2,1784,115,1159,1076,262,2834,406,2091,1606,1784,1975,287,1678,2,
445,595,1160,2292,775,1628,2,2003,176,37,1228,756,1526,2,230,206,
4420,519,2,338,204,3,75,50,895,1368,138,2205,116,246,54,269,54,16,
1448,320,2005,61,531,619,223,168,74,262,256,207,87,1,233,341,552,
156,700,2,2,5,79,339,1220,683,590,188,657,2,1,533,461,18,6,304,113,
332,192,270,5629329,194,32,63,155,2,59,5996289,520,47,2800650,2382,
444,1,2,80,1,1796,1,9,2,2551,1,889,795,2,561,1,4265,1,1,2,1331,3299,
843,2609,155,17,13,72,139,4,2,20,2,169,13,19,46,5,39,96,548,29,2,
2,1,2,1,2,2,7,4,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,353,422,91,5,114,43,14,25,43,2,1,4,
1,10,8,1,23952292,4010273,268,1835,26467,2,2374,3,120,3,6,338,3,
2340,74,540\',
kBL:\'bsXf\'};
```

In short, the response text involve various other dynamic values along with the static data on the website. So the length varies from request to request.
Feel free to add a comment you still have any doubt or Upvote my answer so that it would be useful..

Comment: actually I'm scraping a site and a specific part is missing from body which i need

Comment: That has nothing to do with the length.. You see the reason above for the change in length for different requests

Comment: @SHUVAMJASWAL . print out your response body to check if at all what u need is in the response. and for more help, you can frame your question according to that. The above mentioned length issue doesnt seem to be the prblm in your case...

Comment: I'm using a parser to search for that specific element and in some cases( when something is missing in body) that element is not found

Comment: @SHUVAMJASWAL ..  as i mentioned, the only difference in the length seems to be the txt i explained above. If you think your prblm isnt solved yet, change/ask the question with specifications.